# Why might my first API call run fine, but the second one hang indefinitely?

Tags: node.js, express, response, bloomberg

I am trying to keep a session open with the Bloomberg Public API, relaying calls from my own service's API to it to fetch data. I am running the Node.JS / Express server locally right now. I have an API route that works fine the first time: I send the `GET`, and quickly get the response back. If I then send another `GET` to the same route, and I can see the data that the Bloomberg API returns in my server console, but it seems that the server gets stuck at the `res.send(...)` and I have no Idea why. I've tried numerous things like moving code blocks around and forcefully destroying variables, but to no avail. Do you guys see anything obvious that would/might work?

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var Blpapi = require('./blpapi.model');
var count = 0;

var blpapi = require('blpapi');

// Add 'authenticationOptions' key to session options if necessary.
var session = new blpapi.Session({ serverHost: '10.8.8.1', serverPort: 8194 });
var service_refdata = 1; // Unique identifier for refdata service

session.start();
session.on('SessionStarted', function(m) {
    console.log(m);
    session.openService('//blp/refdata', service_refdata);
});
session.on('ServiceOpened', function(m) {
    console.log(m);
});
session.on('SessionStartupFailure', function(m) {
    console.log('SessionStartupFailure', util.inspect(m));
    session.stop();
    session.destroy();
});
session.on('SessionTerminated', function(m) {
    console.log('Session Terminated');
    session.stop();
    session.destroy();
});

exports.getStock = function (req, res) {
    var stock = req.url.substring(8, req.url.length);
    stock = stock.replace(/_/g, ' ');

    session.on('HistoricalDataResponse', function(m) {
        console.log(m);
        if(m.eventType === 'RESPONSE' && m.correlations[0].value === 101) {
            console.log('send');
            res.send(m.data.securityData);
        }
        else {
            res.send(500);
        }
    });

    newRequest(stock);
};

function newRequest(sec) {
    if(typeof sec !== 'string') return;
    session.request('//blp/refdata', 'HistoricalDataRequest',
        { securities: [sec],
            fields: ['PX_LAST', 'OPEN'],
            startDate: "20140101",
            endDate: "20140301",
            periodicitySelection: "DAILY" }, 101);
}

function handleError(res, err) {
    return res.send(500, err);
}
```

Edit1: If I change the `res.send(m.data.securityData);` to `res.send(201);`, the requests come back fine, so I'm figuring it has to do with that object.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because I was declaring the `session.on('HistoricalDataResponse', ....` statement inside of my route controller. Moving it out and adding a bit of logic around it solved the problem.